# How to redirect incoming traffic to another site instead of a 404 page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7.5

im trying to configure our IIS server to redirect users to another site instead of a 404 page.

First of all, maybe the title of the question is not correct but i have no idea how to ask for it.

Here's the deal:

1. we have lots of documents in our IIS server, these documents are
   reports for our users, might be .pdf, .doc, .xls files etc.
2. currently all of our files are stored in a 2TB HDD but it's getting
   full and we are considering attaching another HDD that will store
   all of our current files ( let's call this HDD history )
3. we have many applications and emails sent that are using the url to download the file hard-coded ( eg. www.somesite.com/documents/file.pdf ) and we need to deliver the files even if a link sent in an email targets the "old" url, but with the new HDD we will create a virtual directory that will be named "historydocuments" so the correct url for the example before    will be www.somesite.com/historydocuments/file.pdf
4. I am trying to do the following: create an url rewrite rule that will try and check if the file exists on the "normal" url (documents) if there's no file there, instead of sending a 404 page, will try to jump to the
   new virtual directory ( historydocuments ) and try to give the user
   the file.

All of this is being done in IIS 7.5, i don't know if URL Rewrite is the correct tool for the job and i haven't found anything on SO or the interwebs, so i'm reaching for an IIS Guru to teach me the way to achieve this.

Here's an image trying to illustrate the issue:
[image]

Here's the web.config section of the URL Rewrite

```
<rule name="CDocuments Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".?" />
    <!--<match url="/cdocuments/(.*)?" />-->
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="/cdocuments/(.*)?" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="/cdocuments/(.*)?" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.172.226/filecheck/default.aspx?file={C:2}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Try searching around this term `
Apache Web Server Configuration for Web Site Redirection`

Comment: iis lets you create virtual directories. there's no need for error documents and whatnot. just create a v-dir for /historydocuments and point it at the old drive. browsers couldn't care less how/where the server is storing data. as long as the url returns what's expected, the data could be on one drive, many drives, or transcribed on the fly by an army of monkeys from paper records.

Comment: why not create a new "newdocs" directory on the new hard drive for new documents?  old urls still work and you send new links in new url.

Comment: Why not just make a custom 404 page, and set it in IIS as the path for the 404 status code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IIS URLRewrite can do this. But you can customize your 404 page on the "documents" directory, where you check if the missing file is actually located in the old directory and redirect user to new url if true. You may see many 404 errors in your log, which is not nice.

Why not just create a new directory for new documents on the new HDD and keep the old name for old files. Old links will still work and you just send you links in new url. You can actually create some meaningful directories to manage your documents such as www.yourdomain/docs/2015/docufile.pdf. The next upgrade will be much easier.

Or use IIS to rewrite

```
www.yourdomain.com/documents/fileno.pdf
```

to

```
www.yourdomain.com/docs/docfind.asp?fname=fileno.pdf
```

and program the docfind.asp to locate the fileno.pdf and redirect user to the real document url

```
www.yourdomain.com/historydocuments/fileno.pdf
```

or

```
www.youdomain.com/newdocuments/fileno.pdf
```

asp or perl script will do it quickly and easily.

The rule should looks like this:

```
            <rule name="cddocuments">
                <match url="cddocuments/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.172.226/filecheck/default.aspx?file={R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Make sure you rename your old document directory.

Comment: So you're suggesting that the V-Dir should target the new HDD and from now on just save the files in there? We thought about it, would be plain and simple, but there are dozens of applications that generate new documents everyday and those applications are so old we don't have the source code anymore, that's why we need to still serve files on the old url. We have even thought about some method to move the files to new HDD as they're created on the old HDD to keep a single V-Dir targeting the new HDD

Comment: if you have to use the "documents" directory for new links, then you can use URLRewrite to re-direct your "documents" directory to a vb script, which will check which directory the document is located and redirect the user to the real location, no 404 error.  See changes in my answer.

Comment: Dude, i'm stuck in this, i tried to do what you suggested but failed miserably, i'll update my question with my web.config section of the rewrite for you to check if there's something missing because no matter what i do, it still doesn't rewrites the URL and the server responds with a 404.

Comment: You need test your url rewrite rule carefully. I think your rule is wrong. It should be very simple rule: match url="cddocments/(.*), action type= rewrite , url="/doc/do find.asp?a={r:1}". My internet is down and when it's back, I can post a complete rule for you. Please try create a simple rule with above matching url.

Comment: If it's still not working, check your access log to see what URL is causing 404.

Comment: Sam,check the rule in my answer to see if it works for you. Your rule has some issues.

Comment: Well, I tried your suggestion and still no dice, strangely enough another rule i tried redirected me as expected, but the filename is not concatenated, i'll update my question with this rule in case you notice something odd in it. Thanks.